# DataLayer Issue on GTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

if pushing datalayer object in window.dataLayer by using vuejs then in the console it's showing but on the Google tag manager event is not creating.

I have tried implementing the following code.

dataLayerUpdateItem(selectedVariation)
{
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

```
if(this.$store.state.cart.items.length)
{
    let products = [];
    let items = [];

    this.$store.state.data_layer_add_to_cart.ecommerce.value = selectedVariation.quantity*selectedVariation.price;

    let options =  Object.values(selectedVariation.options);

    let category = "";

    if(typeof(selectedVariation.categories) != "undefined" && selectedVariation.categories !== null)
        category =  selectedVariation && selectedVariation.categories.length > 0 ? selectedVariation.categories[0].meta_title : "";

    products[0] = {};
    products[0].brand = "";
    products[0].category = category;
    products[0].id = selectedVariation ? selectedVariation.sku : "";
    products[0].name = selectedVariation ? selectedVariation.title : "";
    products[0].price = selectedVariation ? selectedVariation.price : "";
    products[0].quantity = this.quantity;
    products[0].stocklevel = "";
    products[0].variant = options ? options.join(",") : "";

    items[0] = {};
    items[0].google_business_vertical = "retail";
    items[0].id = selectedVariation ? selectedVariation.sku : "";
    items[0].item_brand = "";
    items[0].item_category = category;
    items[0].item_id = selectedVariation ? selectedVariation.sku : "";
    items[0].item_name = selectedVariation ? selectedVariation.title : "";
    items[0].item_variant = options ? options.join(",") : "";
    items[0].price = selectedVariation ? selectedVariation.price : "";
    items[0].quantity = this.quantity;

    this.$store.state.data_layer_add_product_to_cart_eec.ecommerce.add.products = products;
    this.$store.state.data_layer_add_to_cart.ecommerce.items = items;

    let obj1Keys = Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer)));
    let obj2Keys = Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$store.getters.updateDetailsDataLayer)));

    for(let i=0; i<obj1Keys.length; i++) {
        window.dataLayer[i] = window.dataLayer[obj1Keys[i]];
    }

    for(let i=0; i<obj2Keys.length; i++) {
        window.dataLayer[i+obj1Keys.length] = this.$store.getters.updateDetailsDataLayer[obj2Keys[i]];
    }

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer;
}
else
{
    this.$store.state.data_layer_change_detail_view_eec.ecomm_prodid = "";
    this.$store.state.data_layer_change_detail_view_eec.ecomm_totalvalue = "0.00";
    this.$store.state.data_layer_view_item.ecommerce.value = "0.00";
}
```

}